# Naming a screen session in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, gnu-screen

I am running multiple screens from one ssh connection, when I list all of the screens via `screen -ls` the names are not very descriptive and when I have multiple screens it becomes hard to remember what is running on each. Does anyone know how to name these sessions (preferably when creating the screen).

Comment: This question surely belongs on ServerFault?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign name for a screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3202111/608639), [How to rename a gnu screen session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27780/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Rename screen session](https://superuser.com/q/370510/173513) on [Super User](http://superuser.com/), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the `-S` flag:

```
screen -S name_for_this_session
```

Answer (score 0):

```
screen -S sessionname
```

When creating a new session, this option can be used to specify a meaningful name for the session. This name identifies the session for "screen -list" and "screen -r" actions. It substitutes the default [tty.host]

check this http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference for more info...