# How can I assign a name for a screen?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, gnu-screen

I'm using the [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) multiplexer tool on the command shell and open a lot of screens. I then forget which process ID associates with which task.

I would like to set a name for a screen, but I can't find an option in the [man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page).

Currently, listing the screens looks like this:

```
There are screens on:
    5422.pts-1.aws1 (Detached)
    5448.pts-1.aws1 (Detached)
    5027.pts-1.aws1 (Detached)
3 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-sb.
```

And I would like to see something like this:

```
There are screens on:
    5422.logCleanWorker (Detached)
    5448.overNightLongTask(Detached)
    5027.databaseOverNightLongTask (Detached)
3 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-sb.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: the question looks more like it's asking "how to rename existing sessions" rather than "how to start new sessions with a name". In that context, the currently chosen answer is not really appropriate. The correct answer should rather be the one given by `user164176` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3309696/636762

Comment: The names of your screen sessions suggest that you create a new screen session per a single task (maybe a single command). Screen supports [multiple windows](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/#creating), so you can run all these tasks in a single screen session.

Comment: Can this be migrated to SuperUser (or some other StackExchange site)? Obviously it's quite useful to a lot of people, though it's out of the scope of this particular site.

Comment: if you find an option on this site to move it there with all the history, then I would agree moving it

Answer (score 779, accepted):

## To start a new session

`screen -S your_session_name`

## To rename an existing session

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd> sessionname YOUR_SESSION_NAME <kbd>Enter</kbd>

> You must be inside the session

Comment: This is the appropriate solution as it focuses on renaming the existing session rather than creating a new one.

Comment: A quick note on `C-a :` syntax.... "All screen commands are prefixed by an escape key, by default `C-a` (that's Control-a, sometimes written `^a`). To send a literal `C-a` to the programs in screen, use `C-a a`. This is useful when working with screen within screen. For example `C-a a n` will move screen to a new window on the screen within screen." (ref: http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference )

Comment: Much appreciated. Even though I know you can start with a name, I often start without naming, then wish I could later. Thanks!

Comment: agreed after looking at it a couple of years later :D

Comment: Can I bind the `C-a :sessionname NEWNAME` to something quicker to type?  I tried `bind $ sessionname` but now when I `C-a $` it doesn't prompt me for a new name.  Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Pro tip, you can type a prefix of the screenname, so instead of: `screen -r myname`, `screen -r my` will work (if it's a unique prefix).

Answer (score 602):

To create a new screen with the name `foo`, use

```
screen -S foo
```

Then to reattach it, run

```
screen -r foo  # or use -x, as in
screen -x foo  # for "Multi display mode" (see the man page)
```

Comment: In you solution you explain how to create new ones with correct names rather than changing the existing ones. There is none that wants to  terminate the session if it is possible to keep it.

Comment: Scroll down to user164176's answer to see how to rename existing sessions.

Comment: the question looks more like it's asking "how to rename existing sessions" rather than "how to start new sessions with a name". In that context, the currently chosen answer is not really appropriate. The chosen correct answer should rather be the one given by `user164176` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3309696/636762 below

Comment: I searched "ubuntu create a new screen with name" on google and this was first result. Exactly what I was looking for :) thanks

Comment: To rename a session: Ctrl+a, : sessionname YOUR_SESSION_NAME Enter.

Answer (score 54):

As already stated, `screen -S SESSIONTITLE` works for starting a session with a title (`SESSIONTITLE`), but if you start a session and later decide to change its title. This can be accomplished by using the default key bindings:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>

Which prompts:

```
Set windows title to:SESSIONTITLE
```

Change `SESSIONTITLE` by backspacing and typing in the desired title. To confirm the name change and list all titles.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>

Comment: You are treating the terms _session_ and _window_ as interchangeable when they are not. `Ctrl+a`, `A` does not set the _session_ name (`SESSIONNAME`), it only sets the current _window_ title. Titles of windows within a session do not appear in the list of sessions when queried with `screen -list`. The question asks how to set the _session_ name.

Comment: usefull but it changes current window title, not session name.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way is to use Screen with a name:

```
screen -S 'name' 'application'
```

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> = exit and leave the application open

Return to Screen:

```
screen -r 'name'
```

For example, using Lynx with Screen.

Create a screen:

```
screen -S lynx lynx
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> = exit

Later, you can return with:

```
screen -r lynx
```

Comment: Three problems with this.  First, several people have already posted this.  Second, you're telling him basic screen usage stuff he already knows.  Third, you didn't actually answer the question, since he asked how to name an already-existing screen session.

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner to Screen, but I find it immensely useful while restoring lost connections.

Your question has already been answered, but this information might serve as an add on - I use [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) with PuTTY connection manager and name my screens - "tab1", "tab2", etc. - as for me the overall picture of the 8-10 tabs is more important than each individual tab name. I use the 8th tab for connecting to db, the 7th for viewing logs, etc. So when I want to reattach my screens I have written a simple wrapper which says:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -d -r tab$1
```

where first argument is the tab number.

Comment: This might be better done as a bash function.