# GNU screen: set name or title

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have many `screen` sessions open and I cannot recognize which one is which.

I start `screen` with:

```
# screen -d -m -t "myscreen" ./myscript.sh
```

but `screen -ls` just shows this:

```
# screen -ls
There are screens on:
    1167..lh18758   (04/13/2012 09:20:49 PM)        (Detached)
    32040..lh18758  (04/13/2012 09:20:05 PM)        (Detached)
    27775..lh18758  (04/13/2012 09:18:27 PM)        (Detached)
    27751..lh18758  (04/13/2012 09:18:27 PM)        (Detached)
    26604..lh18758  (04/13/2012 09:18:01 PM)        (Detached)
    6879..lh18758   (04/13/2012 09:10:28 PM)        (Detached)
    6347..lh18758   (04/13/2012 09:10:15 PM)        (Detached)
    6371..lh18758   (04/13/2012 09:10:15 PM)        (Detached)
```

It is possible to set names to `screen` session to not see the `6371..lh18758` but a title or name?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3202111/1030301

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify names when you create the sessions.

From the manpage:

> -S sessionname
>
> When  creating  a  new  session, this option can be used to specify a meaningful name for the session. This name identifies the
>   session for "screen -list" and "screen -r" actions. It substitutes the
>   default
>     [tty.host] suffix.

So you would make the command line

```
$ screen -d -m -t "myscreen" -S "MeaningfulName" ./myscript.sh
```