# Docker Node.js environment variables

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to use environment variables on docker only needed for on command. On Mac/Linux I can simple just run `token=1234 node command.js` and token is available as an environment variable. But when I do this with docker `docker exec $CONTAINER nenv token=123 node command.js` I get `unknown command token=123`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812548/how-do-you-set-an-environment-variable-in-a-running-docker-container

Answer (score 1):

I don't use node env,
I recommend to do following:

create **config** folder

put this in **config/index.js**

```
var
    nconf = require('nconf'),
    path = require('path');

nconf.env().argv();

nconf.file('local', path.join(__dirname, 'config.local.json'));
nconf.file(path.join(__dirname, 'config.json'));

module.exports = nconf;
```

create files: **config/config.json** (template of config) and **config/config.local.json** (copy of template with real configuration)

for example:

```
{
  "app": {
    "useCluster": false,
    "http": {
      "enabled": true,
      "port": 8000,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "https": {
      "enabled": false,
      "port": 443,
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "certificate": {
        "key": "server.key",
        "cert": "server.crt"
      }
    },
    "env": "production",
    "profiler": false
  },
  "db": {
    "driver": "mysql",
    "host": "address here",
    "port": 3306,
    "user": "username here",
    "pass": "password here",
    "name": "database name here"
  },
}
```

use in beginning of Your app: `var config = require('./config');`

and use **config** object whenever You need:

```
var config = require('./config'),
    cluster = require('./components/cluster'),
    http = require('http'),
    ...
    ...
    https = require('https');

cluster.start(function() {
    if (config.get('app:http:enabled')) {
        var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
        httpServer.listen(config.get('app:http:port'), config.get('app:http:host'),
            function () {
                winston.info('App listening at http://%s:%s', config.get('app:http:host'), config.get('app:http:port'));
            });
    }

    if (config.get('app:https:enabled')) {
        var httpsServer = https.createServer({
            key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'certificates', config.get('app:https:certificate:key'))),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'certificates', config.get('app:https:certificate:cert')))
        }, app);
        httpsServer.listen(config.get('app:https:port'), config.get('app:https:host'),
            function () {
                winston.info('App listening at https://%s:%s', config.get('app:https:host'), config.get('app:https:port'));
            });
    }
});
```

this example is more accurate way to have environment based configs. for example:  **config.local.json** configuration that will be added to **.gitignore** and so on...

Comment: This approach seems like unnecssary work in our use case. We clone our repo into our fresh docker image. So with your approach we would have to create a config file from docker cmd line then run the script

Comment: no, just create file config.local.json in docker app, and it will keep configuration, also You can try to modify config/index.js to read configuration from arguments, using node-argument-parser it's good package.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT caused by my stupidness !

You can't set new env var using docker on an existing docker.
You have to do this when you build it (using Dockerfile or docker-compose), or when you run it (using  `docker run $CONTAINER -e "name=value" command`).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you need to simply retrieve certain configurations from the command (at `docker run` time) you can do it simply by switching from node env (`process.env`) to argv usage.
Such casers are not uncommon (`docker-compose`), and could be done in very easy way.

`npm install yargs --save`

run code with `docker run` or `docker exec`:

`docker exec $CONTAINER node command.j --token 123`

then in code:

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv;
...
let boo = do.something(argv.token);
```