# Updating Environment Variables of a Container using Docker

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I've setup a server with multiple docker containers, accessible with [jwilders nginx reversre proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy). When you run the containers you can set the VIRTUAL_HOST environment variable. I've been trying to figure out a way of updating these after a container was launched.

A solution posted [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8838) :

> You just stop docker daemon and change container config in
>
> `/var/lib/docker/containers/[container-id]/config.json`

Requires you to stop the docker daemon, but I would prefer not to have to resort to that.

Another [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22490), uses docker commit to preserve the instance information:

> Having said that, you -can- preserve filesystem changes in the
>   container, by committing it as a new image;
>
> ```
> $ docker run -it --name=foobar alpine sh
> $ docker commit foobar mynewimage
> $ docker rm foobar
> $ docker run -it --name=foobar mynewimage sh
> ```

Though this also seems to be a bit over the top for just changing an environment variable.

I've looked in [docker update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/), but that is mainly for reconfiguring container resources.

Of course, if I have no other choice I will use either of the methods above, but I'm wondering if anyone has found some other solution?

Comment: I think it is better to update a Dockerfile, with some `ENV abc 123` or `ENV abc=123 def=456` and rebuild/relaunch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set an environment variable in a running docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27812548/608639)

Comment: tldr the quick way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812548/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-in-a-running-docker-container/56965134#56965134

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Destroy your container and start a new one up with the new environment variable using `docker run -e ...`. It's identical to changing an environment variable on a running process, you stop it and restart with a new value passed in. Replace the concept of restarting a process with destroying and recreating a new container.

If your container contains files that cannot be lost, then you should be using volumes. The other contents of the container filesystem should be either disposable or immutable.

Comment: Well yes, true, one could default back to recreating the container, and I did in the end since I'm using a volume, but I was more curious if there was a way to do so as a kind of running patch?

Comment: Docker doesn't provide a way to modify an environment variable in a running container because the OS doesn't provide a way to modify an environment variable in a running process. You need to destroy and recreate.

Comment: @BMitch That doesn't make sense. You can stop and start containers.

Comment: @Lamp the update command doesn't require that you restart the container to take effect. If you change something that requires a container restart, then the workflow is to replace the container instead.