# Is it possible to make changes in existing environment file once we deploy docker container?

Tags: docker

I have environment file which i used for docker deployment,is it possible to update same environment file after docker run?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please add a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Questions must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set an environment variable in a running docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27812548/608639), [Updating Environment Variables of a Container using Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38587741/608639), etc.

Comment: what do you mean by environment file? Do you mean the Dockerfile or environment variables?

Comment: I think he means https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/