# How to set environment variable in Circle CI to use in application as process.env.FOO

Tags: docker, circleci

For example I've setup `name: FOO value: 'bar'`.

I've validated that the key value works. Because what *does* work is:

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker: 
      - image: circleci/node:10.17.0
    steps:
      - run: |
          node something $FOO
```

However, the following *does not* work:

Now when I deploy and try to use it in my application it returns undefined:

```js
console.log(process.env.FOO); // returns undefined
```

I tried setting it under the 'environment' key in the config.yml file:

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker: 
      - image: circleci/node:10.17.0
      environment:
        - FOO # note, don't use $FOO
    steps:
      - run: |
        node something $FOO
        ssh $MACHINE -- 'cd /home/ && docker build -t myApp . docker restart myApp'
```

But still no change.

Should I perhaps pass the variables to the build script in the ssh command?

Any ideas?

---

update based on Delena's tip

Kept `./circle-ci/config.yml` as:

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker: 
      - image: circleci/node:10.17.0
      environment:
        FOO: $FOO
```

Then in the docker-compose file:

```
myApp:
  environment:
    - FOO
```

Will accept the answer when the build is green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to access the environment variable from an app that runs in a Docker container, but you're not setting the environment variable in the container.

If that's the case, you can check out [How to set an environment variable in a running docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812548/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-in-a-running-docker-container), but it looks like you'll have to stop the container and restart it again with the environment variable.

You could do something like:

`ssh $MACHINE -- 'cd /home/ && docker build -t myApp && docker stop myApp && docker run -e "FOO=$FOO"'`

Also check out the [ENV (environment variables)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) section in the `docker run` docs.

Comment: That makes sense. I am not running Docker using the `docker run`. But docker-compose. Can I also set env variables using docker-compose instead of the `-e` flag on docker run?  (I'm new to Docker)

Comment: Oké. Found it, Have added it under an `environment` key in the docker-compose.yml file.  (i.e. `myApp: environment: - FOO`) Should I then also refer to these variables in the Dockerfile itself? (i.e. `ENV FOO $FOO`)

Comment: I don't think you need to. Only adding it your docker-compose.yml file should be fine. Since you're using Docker Compose, you could then use `docker-compose build myApp` to rebuild the container and `docker-compose up --force-recreate` to stop and restart the app. Or maybe just `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate` should work.

Comment: Thank you so much . Trying this out. Last thing, the 'environment' setting should then entirely be removed from `.circle-ci/config.yml`? Or is that making the reference for the docker-compose file?